# Making dates not selectable in Shiny inputDate

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Im currently trying to use the Shiny input dates and want to make some dates not selectable. ie in January I only want to be able to select the 3rd,10th,11th,12th, 16th and 21st. This would be similar in each month as my underlying dataset dates in them I would like to use with this function. Any help appreciated

In my ui.R I have 
        dateInput("date2", "Date:")

Comment: You can create a data frame of your unique dates: `options <- unique(df$date)` and use those values as your input options: `selectInput("date2", "Date:", options)`

Comment: thanks that works as a selectInput but was wondering if it could be used somehow with dateInput as I wanted the calendar to be used for a selection with non valid dates greyed out.

Comment: It looks like dateInput is based on bootstrap-datepicker, which [allows you to disable days of the week](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#daysofweekdisabled) using `daysOfWeekDisabled` and is supported in Shiny. It also looks like there is [something brewing](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/174) to add the `datesDisabled` functionality to Shiny, which would allow you to pass a vector of allowable dates, but it doesn't look like it's finished yet.

Comment: thanks Jeff much appreciated ill keep an eye out for future updates